# Using percent ( % ) sign in react-router :id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to use a percent sign in a react-router id. As using `%` in URI is forbidden, I have to encode my URI manually to be able to use this percent sign. Using a Link, I therefore use the encodeURI function to encode the URI:

```
<Link to={`/r/${encodeURI(my_str_with_unencoded_percent_sign)}`} >
```

In the source code of my page, I can see that the link uses `%25` and not `%`.

Still, when clicking on the link, I get the error "URIError: malformed URI sequence" (in another part of my code, I have a 
`<Match pattern="/r/:id" …`).

What did I do wrong? It seems the url is decoded *before* being passed to the parseParams function of react-router, which tries to decode it a second time, which leads to this error.

I found issues such as https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/issues/461 or https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/issues/461, but I didn't find any solution to this problem: how can I use a percent sign in a react-router :id ?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a working modified version of the [URL Parameters](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params) example provided by Recat-Training.

Copy paste the below into your index.js and test it to see it works. I was going to provide a codesandbox of this for you, but their internal routing has issues that cause the screen to go black even with uri encoded % signs... I did test this locally and works like a charm.

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

const ParamsExample = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <h2>Accounts</h2>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to={`/${encodeURI("%netflix")}`}>Netflix</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/zillow-group">Zillow Group</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/yahoo">Yahoo</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/modus-create">Modus Create</Link></li>
      </ul>

      <Route path="/:id" component={Child} />
    </div>
  </Router>
)

const Child = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <h3>ID: {match.params.id}</h3>
  </div>
)

render(<ParamsExample />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. Indeed, your solution works when I click the links displayed on the page, but it does not work when refreshing the page: if I click on the « Netflix » link, it correctly shows me the ID, as expected, and it changes the URL in my web navigator to "http://domain.tld/%netflix". When refreshing using F5, or ctrl+R, I still get the same error.

Is that expected?

Test code is here (only here for easy zip download, as you said, codesandbox is broken and shows a web page): https://codesandbox.io/s/zj7ok3l5x

Comment: You're getting a `malformed url` error from trying to navigate directly to a url that contains a `%` or a url that contains an encoded `%`?

Comment: Well, the url contains a % (non encoded, in the url bar), while it should contain an encoded % as I use the encodeURI function. Still, react-router understand the encoding, as clicking on the links redirects to the correct Route.

Comment: But the link directs you to the encoded version. `to={`/${encodeURI("%netflix")}`}`. If you want people to be able to direct link with a `%` in the url, I would look at the `window.location.pathname` prior to any routing in my app. If any characters that need to be encoded are present, redirect to an encoded version of the url.

Comment: The link should directs me to the encoded version, but it is not: if I look in the url shown in my navigator, the url is not encoded (with the codesandbox.io above). I made a video to show you the issue: https://ptpb.pw/UBJc.mkv

Comment: This is a bug in the [react router history library](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/issues/505).  [This PR](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/pull/751) will need to get merged, and react router will need to bump its version.