# React decoding with % in URL causes error

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In order to allow for URL parameters to have percent signs, I use this code:

```
<Link to={"project/" + encodeURIComponent(projectName.replace("%", "%25"))}>{projectName}</Link>
```

The link above takes me to the `projects` page. This is how I decode the projectName parameter on the `projects` page:

```
const projectName = decodeURIComponent(match.params.projectName);
```

This code works. However, if I refresh the `projects` page or use the browser back/forward button to navigate to the `projects` page, I get an error when decoding. `URIError: URI malformed`

It looks like the match.params.projectName is already decoded after refreshing / navigating with forward / back buttons. This causes the error to occur.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by the way React Router decodes URIs. Specifically the way it handles the % character.

I solved this issue by replacing every **%** in the URI parameter with some random text. Something that would never happen to show up in your program. ie...**123PERCENTREPLACEMENT123**.

It is basically a manual encoding of the percent sign that I must decode on the other end by replacing that same unique string with a % sign.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same problem.  Apologies for posting my response as an answer, but I have yet to get enough rep to comment and this response is a bit packed with details.  In the comments of an answer to the post [Using percent ( % ) sign in react-router :id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47679010/using-percent-sign-in-react-router-id) you will find that @james-conkling mentions that the bug is in the react-router history library:

> This is a bug in the react router history library. This PR will need to get merged, and react router will need to bump its version.

The PR referenced is [#751](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/pull/751) and has since been merged (June 12, 2020).  Unfortunately it seems that, as of time of this writing, the latest version of react-router is v5.2.0 (May 11, 2020) and the PR above likely won't be included until react-router v6.  I wasn't able to find any estimates for when React Router will release v6.  There is a version v6.0.0-beta that was tagged on June 19, 2020.
I'm unable to test v6 in my app, and will be unable to, for an unrelated  reason:
[React: 'Redirect' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63690695/react-redirect-is-not-exported-from-react-router-dom)  ( beware of breaking API changes when upgrading to v6 )